# Make a character as if it is inside the background but not

Tags: javascript, html, css, news-ticker

I don't feel my headline ticker is good to see for my visitors. it is in [please check this link](http://savageryonline.com/index.php)

what I need is to make the headline words inside of the background but readable enough. it is like a shadow. anyone can help please, this site must be submitted tomorrow and be soon launched.

the headline ticker I use is in javascript as below:

```
<script language="javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var lgth=0;
var info1="Selamat Datang di www.savageryonline.com";
var info2="SavageryOnline ... Tempat Belanja Aman dan Nyaman Bersama Keluarga!";
var info3="Belanja Super Hemat! Kualitas Super Hebat!";

dataTampil=new items(info1,info2,info3);
var ini=0;
var st=0;
var x=dataTampil[0].length;
function items() {
lgth=items.arguments.length;
for (i=0; i<lgth; i++) this[i]=items.arguments[i];
}
function newheadlinez(){
var datShowNow=dataTampil[ini].substring(0,st)+""; document.getElementById("headline").innerHTML=datShowNow; document.getElementById("headline").style.color="white"; document.getElementById("headline").style.cursor="pointer";

if(st++==x) {
st=0; setTimeout("newheadlinez()",5000); ini++; if(ini==lgth) ini=0; x=dataTampil[ini].length;
}
else setTimeout("newheadlinez()",50);
}
    //]]>
    </script>
```

these words I need to change like shadow but not and as if it is united with the background. Sorry, I can't give you screenshot for this.

> ```
> "Selamat Datang di www.savageryonline.com"
> "SavageryOnline ... Tempat Belanja Aman dan Nyaman Bersama Keluarga!"
> "Belanja Super Hemat!
> ```

I try to change it with CSS but it doesn't work. (i'm bad in css).

UPDATE:

I fiddle out the script:
[**JsFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/91eqyz7c/)

Comment: please make your code more readable by either creating a code snippet or a jsfiddle. thanks

Comment: @Sai I've just updated in JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to try shadow effect..try adding this in `#topup`

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
```

Comment: not the background, but the headline words which have to be changed

Answer (score 0):

try using opacity property:

```
{
opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: opacity:0.5; not compatible in mostly users' browsers used.

Comment: @HermanNz unless your entire customer base uses IE8, you should be fine http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity

Comment: Its compatible if you use it this way:

    {
     -o-opacity:0.5;
     -moz-opacity:0.5;
     -webkit-opacity:0.5;
     -ms-opacity:0.5;
    }

Comment: Also if it turns out not to be supported, its not really going to have any significant impact on the user.  For 99% of users I personally would just go ahead with this.